# Rectangle width estimation for kernel image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, bounding-box, kernel-density

I'm trying to estimate the width of the kernel used for deblurring an image. I have the kernel image with very low resolution. hen I tried to zoom the kernel image and looked, it is showing in 5 pixels in horizontal and 5 pixels in vertical direction.
Till now I have tried the basic code to extract the bounding box of the rectangle to identify width and height but I'm not getting any results.

[image]
[image]

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
areas = [cv2.contourArea(c) for c in contours]
print(areas)
max_index = np.argmin(areas)
cnt=contours[max_index]
print(max_index)

x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
print(w,h,x,y)
cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
cv2.imshow('Show',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

When I tried to execute this code, I get the entire image coordinates as rectangle coordinates

Comment: I recommend you to check if there is any white frame covering entire image.
`print(img[0, 0])`.  Also you should  share the `areas` and `max_index` output so that we can help you.

Comment: @Bhoke areas= 182397.0 and max_index =0  and if I print img[0,0], I get 48. What does it mean?

Comment: img[0][0] is the value of the first pixel in the image. `cv2.findContours` function finds non-zero elements in your image. Thus, you need to apply threshold to your image first.

Comment: the kernel you have shared is 3x3 pixels btw.

Comment: I have added ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,1) threshold before finding contours and I get w,h of kernel as 7,7

Comment: What kind of blur is it -- Gaussian, motion blur, defocus?